# Inequality questions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, fractions

$$K=\frac{B}{A-B} $$
$$A>B>0$$

Is it possible to prove mathematically that as I **increase** A and B (by different numbers), while keeping A>B, K will also increase?
My thought is as we increase both A and B, A-B will get closer to 0, which will increase K.

Comment: No. Increase $B$ to whatever you want, and increase $A$ to something very large.

Answer (score 1):

let $f(x) = {1 \over x-1}$ and note that for $x>1$ that $f$ is decreasing.

You have $K = f({A \over B})$. Note that I can increase both $A,B$ (while maintaining $A > B$) and have the value of
${A \over B}$ increase or decrease. Hence $K$ can increase or decrease.

If ${A \over B}$ increases then $K$ will decrease.

Answer (score 0):

$K$ needs not increase because you can take $A = 2B \implies K = \dfrac{1}{2}$ a constant. And to see $K$ could even be decreasing, you can take $A = B^2\implies K = \dfrac{B}{B^2-B} = \dfrac{1}{B-1}, B > 1$ clearly decreases as $B$ increases. And to show the possibility for $K$ to increase, simply take $A = B+1\implies K = B$ will increase with $B$.

Comment: Is there a way to show when will K increase?

Comment: @CSDUG : I updated my answer with a simple example that has $K$ increase. In brief, any thing can happen here since $A,B$ very wildly...

Answer (score 0):

We can use the total differential to check this :

$$K=\frac B {A-B}$$

$$dK =  \frac {\partial K}{\partial A} dA + \frac{\partial K}{\partial B}dB$$

$$dK = \left(\frac {-B}{(A-B)^2}\right){}dA + \left( \frac 1{A-B} + \frac{B}{(A-B)^2}\right)dB$$

$$dK = \left({\frac {-B}{(A-B)^2}}\right){}dA + \left(\frac{A}{(A-B)^2}\right)dB$$

$$dK = \left( \frac 1 {(A-B)^2}\right)\left( -BdA+AdB \right)$$

So we have three possibilities :

- **$dK > 0$** This requires $AdB > BdA$
- **$dK=0$** This requires $AdB=BdA$
- **$dK < 0$** This requires $AdB < BdA$

> My thought is as we increase both A and B, A-B will get closer to 0, which will increase K.

So this is not generally true.  The effect will depend on the relative values of $A$, $B$ and the changes in those values.  The condition $A>B$ does not change this.